Apex LSP has no output
I am trying to write an ide extension for apex, and have been unable to get the language server to work. The command I am using is (in my dir with .sfdx/sfdx-project.json:
java -cp apex-jorje-lsp.jar -Ddebug.internal.errors=true -Ddebug.semantic.errors=true apex.jorje.lsp.ApexLanguageServerLauncher

But nothing prints to the screen and I am unable to access any LSP features. For context this is how I start the server in the extension:
use std::path::PathBuf;
use zed::LanguageServerId;
use zed_extension_api::{self as zed, Result};

struct ApexExtension;

impl zed::Extension for ApexExtension {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self
    }

    fn language_server_command(
        &mut self,
        _language_server_id: &LanguageServerId,
        worktree: &zed::Worktree,
    ) -> Result<zed::Command> {
        let Some(uber_jar) = worktree.which("apex-jorje-lsp.jar") else {
            return Err("Apex JAR not found".into());
        };
        let Some(java_path) = worktree.which("java") else {
            return Err("java not in path".into());
        };
        const APEX_LANGUAGE_SERVER_MAIN: &str = "apex.jorje.lsp.ApexLanguageServerLauncher";

        Ok(zed::Command {
            command: java_path,
            args: vec![
                "-cp".to_string(),
                uber_jar,
                "-Ddebug.internal.errors=true".to_string(),
                "-Ddebug.semantic.errors=false".to_string(),
                APEX_LANGUAGE_SERVER_MAIN.to_string(),
            ],
            env: Default::default(),
        })
    }
}

zed::register_extension!(ApexExtension);



I have been playing around with this recently too.
I'm able to get the LSP launched using Azul Zulu OpenJDK 11.
My command looks something like:

[absolute path to Zulu binary] -jar [path to apex-jorje-lsp.jar]

I'm new to rust and have been using this to help learn. Message me, maybe we can collaborate if you have something in the works

This is the response I got from the maintainer's: "The Apex LS is using the Microsoft Language Server Protocol, which means you will need a language client implementation. I would recommend finding an Rust implementation to use in your extension."

I guess that makes sense. Looking at the vs-code extension GitHub here they start the server and then the client on the next line.

Have you been able to launch the server and open the language server logs in Zed?

I'm able to launch it but not connect and nothing get's printed out to the logs other than "Starting..." or whatever the startup message is
